# remove characters after a certain character

Tags: perl, split

How can I remove characters from a string after a certain character (for ex:"**.**")?

I have the next string **12345.678**. I want to remove all the characters after "." and get **12345**. The number of characters after "." is variable.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "next string"?  is this part of a bigger string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '12345.678';

# remove everything from . on
$string =~ s/\..*//s;
```

`\.` matches a literal `.`;  `.*` matches anything remaining in the string (with the /s flag to make it include newlines, which by default it doesn't).

It is also possible you are looking for:

```
$number = 12345.678;
$number = int $number;
```

If you want to get what's after the `.` also, do:

```
my ($before, $after) = split /\./, $string, 2;
```

Comment: thank you, I have another question, how can I do to get the number after "." (to get 678)?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
 /\b([^\.]*)\.([0-9a-z]*)\b/$1/;
```

Answer (score 1):

See [perldoc -f](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) index:

```
$x = "12345.678";

$y = substr($x, 0, index($x, '.'));
```

Comment: you should always check if index succeeds; because it returns -1 on failure, it doesn't work well otherwise.  for instance, if `$x` is `'12345'`, `$y` will be `'1234'`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution using [regexps](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) (please, study that document, so you can learn doing it yourself...):

```
my $num = "12345.678";
$num =~ /(.*)\.+/;
print $1;
```

Answer (score 0):

depends what environment you're using and tools you have available but something like this would work in bash

`sed -e "s/\..*$//"`

would work. . is escaped "." second . the matches anything and * matches 0 or more times, $ matches end of line

Comment: Ah, I only answer questions when drunk. They should use system then to run sed

Comment: Yes, you should be really drunk to use `system` and `sed` to cut a piece from a string with Perl... :-)))

Comment: You need to be drunk to use Perl don't you? I thought that was a system requirement

Answer (score 0):

Using [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
my ($num) = split(/\./, "12345.678");
```