# How do I remove characters after a specific character number

Tags: sql, ms-access, character

I have a column with uncertain birth date information, displayed in one ot the following ways (where 0 means digits 0–9):

- 0000?
- 0000??
- 0000!!
- 0000 ?
- *et sim.*

I would like to remove all characters following the first four digits. I have tried using variants of `UPDATE [test] SET BYEAR = left(BYEAR,LEN(FAAR)-4);`, tried swapping it with right, selecting different numbers to remove, but haven’t found a way to specifically tell it to *keep the first four numbers and delete the rest*.

All help would be much appreciated.

A similar question for [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268667/remove-characters-after-a-certain-character), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904746/how-to-remove-all-characters-after-a-specific-character-in-python) have been posted, but I have not found a solution for this in Access/SQL. I am working on a locally stored db, which when linked will be run on an Oracle server.

Comment: Oracle, Access or both?

Comment: Why don't you just SELECT SUBSTR(ColumnName, 1, 4)

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me why `left()` is not appropriate or why you need `len()`. Do you mean that the four first digits may not be at the start of the string? E.g. `'Foo 0879 Bar!!'`?

Comment: you can try like as.....    SET BYEAR = left(BYEAR,4)

Comment: Please give better (more varied) sample data in your question(s). As Gordon wrote, for your examples `Left(BYEAR, 4)` would suffice.

Comment: @Aleksej I added info on the server.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have tried making it clear now that the 0s represented digits and only digits, i.e. *not* `*0000*`, always `0000*`.

Comment: I have tried updating my answer to clarify as per your comments. Please advice if more information is needed; please remove downvotes if it is now clear what I am asking. Also, I am not sure having the Oracle tag is appropriate, as I am working locally at the time being.

Comment: For Oracle, what I posted should work

Comment: @André I have provided all the data necessary, actually. But a non-minimum reprex sample could be provided if necessary.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález As to the `len()` question: I don’t know; it was a solution I found via another SO question, which worked for some of the things I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MS Access, you can keep the first four characters by doing:

```
UPDATE [test]
    SET BYEAR = left(BYEAR, 4);
```

This does not check that the first four characters are actually *digits*, but it does do what you want for the data you have provided.

Comment: Is there any way to make it check for numbers first? It shouldn’t be necessary, but for later usage, it would be nice to know how to.

Comment: @CannedMan . . . It is possible to do, but not in a way that works in both MS Access and Oracle.

Comment: If there is a pure SQL way of doing it, that would have been a nice addition to your answer, but I’m assuming, as per your reply—being that such a solution would not work both in MSA and Oracle—that there isn’t.

Comment: @CannedMan . . . The overlap between MS Access and Oracle is many things, but I would not call it "pure SQL".

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can try the following:

```
WITH TEST(T) AS
(
    SELECT 'xx0000?' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '0000???' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '0000  ?' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'xx00009' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '000099?' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(T, '[0-9]{4}')
FROM TEST

REGEXP_SUBSTR(T,'[0-9]{4}')
----------------------------
0000
0000
0000
0000
0000
```

In your situation:

```
update yourTable set yourField = REGEXP_SUBSTR(yourField , '[0-9]{4}')
```